# Changing the file name of the pdf generated by emacs in Latex/AUCTeX mode

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm using AUCTeX mode in emacs, and I want the generated pdf (after I run `C-c C-c`) to be in the parent directory instead of the current one.
In other words, I want to be able to change the filename of the generated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, this is what you're looking for.

> -- User Option: TeX-output-dir
>
> ```
> Set this option to the path of a directory where output files will
> be placed.  The output files include those that are produced by
> applications running under AUCTeX, temporary files related to
> region processing and the preview-latex files.  If a relative path
> is specified, it is interpreted as being relative to the master
> file in a multifile document.
>
>  This is a buffer local variable and must be set separately for all
> documents and all files in a multifile document.  For example,
>      %%% Local Variables:
>      %%% mode: latex
>      %%% TeX-output-dir: "build"
>      %%% End:
> ```

Comment: what should I write in my `~/.emacs.el` file ?

Comment: The easy way is to edit a TeX file and then `C-h v TeX-output-dir` and in the help buffer click or select the option *Customize*. This will put you in the Customize buffer, where you can just enter the value and click *Apply and Save* button. That will write it into the init file for you.